# Provider com.sun.xml.rpc.client.ServiceFactoryImpl not found

Tags: java, soap

I'm trying to make a call to a web service with following code:

```
/* 
 * A sample Java code for the Termine Web Service.
 */

import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.rpc.*;
import javax.xml.rpc.encoding.XMLType;

public class termine
{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {

    String sentence = "Technical terms are important for knowledge mining, especially in the bio-medical area where vast amount of documents are available.";

    String wsdlURL = "http://www.nactem.ac.uk/software/termine/webservice/termine.wsdl";
    URL url = new URL(wsdlURL);
    String targetNamespace = "urn:termine";
    String   serviceName = "termine";
    String      portName = "termine_porttype";
    String operationName = "analyze";
    QName    serviceQN   = new QName(targetNamespace, serviceName);
    QName       portQN   = new QName(targetNamespace, portName);
    QName  operationQN   = new QName(targetNamespace, operationName);

    try
    {
      ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();
      Service service = serviceFactory.createService(url, serviceQN);

      Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
      call.setProperty(Call.ENCODINGSTYLE_URI_PROPERTY, "");
      call.setProperty(Call.OPERATION_STYLE_PROPERTY, "wrapped");
      call.setTargetEndpointAddress("http://www.nactem.ac.uk:9000/termine");

      call.setPortTypeName(portQN);
      call.setOperationName(operationQN);

      call.removeAllParameters();
      call.addParameter("src",           XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
      call.addParameter("input_format",  XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
      call.addParameter("output_format", XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
      call.addParameter("stoplist",      XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);
      call.addParameter("filter",        XMLType.XSD_STRING, ParameterMode.IN);

      Object[] inParams = new Object[] {sentence, "", "xml", "", ""};

      call.setReturnType(XMLType.XSD_STRING);

      System.out.println(call.invoke(inParams));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
  }
}
```

However, I receive the following error.

javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.rpc.client.ServiceFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.xml.rpc.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:44)
    at javax.xml.rpc.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:137)
    at javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory.newInstance(ServiceFactory.java:58)
    at com.ivita.termExtraction.termine.main(termine.java:31)

From reading about similar problems on the web I got the impression that I'm not using the right libraries. In my pom.xml I have the following dependencies provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Could you please help me to resolve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following dependency to my pom.xml solved the problem (partially because other dependencies seem to be still missing).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```